# 324 error::empty response, django

Tags: python, django, google-chrome

I have a django api which returns content fine in my localhost. But when I run it production. it giving me 324 error [ empty content response error]. 
I had printed api response which is fine. But even before api runs for completions, chrome browser throwing 324 error.

When I researched a bit. it look like socket connection is dead in client side. I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

This could be specific to the server you are using. First try clearing your cookies, but if that does not work, that means you have a faulty server and I don't know how to fix that other than getting another one.